# Integrating SVN with Notepad++?

Tags: svn, version-control, notepad++

The version control in our office is nearly nonexistent, which has obviously led to lots of headaches. We'd like to set something up with SVN and Notepad++... Anyone have any idea of how to accomplish this? I've started researching and came across this site:

http://www.switchonthecode.com/tech-news/notepadplusplus-subversion-plugin

Has anyone ever tried using this? Or anything similar? Any suggestions?

Comment: Side note: I've been using Subversion for a while and I sometimes regret not having chosen a different version control tool. Just don't rush into Subversion without having evaluated other alternatives.

Comment: Sounds pretty cool. I'm currently just using TortoiseSVN and Notepad++ separately.

Answer (score 9):

Tortoise SVN at: http://www.incrediblejunior.com/npp_plugins/

Comment: The best plugin for mixing SVN and Notepad++.

Comment: Not a bad plugin, but doesn't add much over navigating to a file explorer. No new menu, context menu, icons, diff indication, etc. Perhaps this isn't possible with a Notepad++ plugin (I don't know). But I was hoping for a tighter integration, something like the VisualSVN tool for Visual Studio.

Answer (score 6):

Unless you're forcing everyone to use Notepad++, it's better to find a more universal client like [SmartSVN](https://www.smartsvn.com/) or [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/).  From the plugin website, it looks like it's calling TortoiseSVN under the hood anyways.

Comment: I don't mind using TortoiseSVN as the undercore technology... But I'd like to have some sort of interface to use it in Notepad++ as well

Comment: @fseto - this plugin integrates TortoiseSVN and Notepad++ . it is not a separate solution.

Answer (score 5):

I use the bundled Light Explorer on the left pane. I just right-click a file, select 'standard menu', and there's my shell menu with TortoiseSVN. Use "Alt+A" to open the left pane.

Comment: This may be an old solution, but I highly recommend it.  I was looking for a way to do this today and after doing all the hassle above, I figured I would try the explorer plugin (never have before)  this allows me to checkout my projects, favorite them, and even use tsvn right within notepad++

HIGHLY recommend going this route.

Answer (score 5):

Using Notepad++ v6.6.9, I've installed the aforementioned [Tortoise SVN plugin](http://www.incrediblejunior.com/npp_plugins/) v. 2.195, but there are two very useful additions to the information provided to be able to make proper use of this plugin:

- If getting the error *"Can't locate SVN information"*, you might need to update where it finds the TortoiseProc.exe-file. To update this goto *Plugins > Tortoise SVN > TSVN - Open config file* and update the file location to where you have this located in your installation. (Note that you might fiddle a little bit to be able to write to this file if you are not the administrator)
- Secondly to get the project/solution commands working you need to update where to find the solution root, and this can be done like this:

  - Open the *Plugins > SolutionHubUI > SolutionHubUI - Show*
  - Name your new solution, i.e. "My solution", and possibly fill in the solution dir
  - Add an attribute where key is *svn_root_dir*, and the value is your base svn folder (i.e. without the .svn-part)
  - Hit *Save solution*, **and** connect the solution by typing *tsvn* into the connections part in the upper part of the window, and then do a *Save connections*

After doing both of these my installation now gives me proper use of Tortoise SVN through Notepad++, and I can both do the project options, i.e. project update and project commit, and local file modifications, diffs, reverts, and so on.

Do also note that since only one connection to *tsvn* is possible at the time, this means that if you want to change the main project/solution, you need to add multiple solutions and even more crucial make the *tsvn* connections point to the correct solution!

Answer (score 1):

You can open a diff file in Notepad++ and it will display the colours as desired.  Simply save the diff output with extension .diff

e.g.  svn diff -c 37190 > changes.diff

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add the TortoiseSVN-plugin commands into the context menu you have to alter the `contextMenu.xml` file of Notepad++. The file can be found in the AppData Roaming folder `%APPDATA%\Notepad++` or can be opened directly in Notepad++ via menu *Settings* → *Edit Popup ContextMenu*.

An entry for an SVN update command inside a submenu named "TortoiseSVN" may look like:

```xml
<Item FolderName="TortoiseSVN"
      PluginEntryName="Tortoise SVN"
      PluginCommandItemName="TSVN - File update"
      ItemNameAs="Update"/>
```

- *FolderName* is the name of the submenu
- *PluginEntryName* is the name of the TortoiseSVN-plugin
- *PluginCommandItemName* is the name of the TortoiseSVN-plugin command (like in the *Plugins* menu)
- *ItemNameAs* is a custom name for the menu item

For more information about customizing Notepad++ context menu take a look at its [documentation](https://npp-user-manual.org/docs/config-files/#the-context-menu-contextmenu-xml).