# how do i connect to a svn repo from notepad++ and check out a file

Tags: svn, notepad++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Integrating SVN with Notepad++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4544939/integrating-svn-with-notepad)

how do i connect to a svn repo from notepad++ and check out a file

[Same question is asked here as well](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12697061/1582805)

Comment: Why do you want to use a text editor to use SVN? Why not use an SVN client instead?

Answer (score 1):

[Here is a plugin](http://www.incrediblejunior.com/npp_plugins/) that integrates Tortoise SVN into Notepad++.

Another way to achieve this is to use the [Explorer plugin](http://sourceforge.net/projects/npp-plugins/files/) and then simply display it in Notepad++  and, having TortoiseSVN installed on your system, right-click any file or folder to update/commit/revert it...

You can add it from the Notepadd++ menu : `Plugins` > `Plugin Manage` > `Show Plugin Manager then select the`Explorer`plugin and click the`Install` button.